# Having problem in rendering subreport existing in group footer

Tags: activereports

I have to fix a report designed by Acive report and I am fairly new to this. The problem occurs after converting this report from frame work 1 to 2 .Nothing is changed but sub report showing the total count does not show up.
I have a main report(RptReport.vb) having a group containg 6 subreports in its footer(GrpFooter).
It Has:

Report Header
Page header
GrpPageNumbering
   Application's Icon
   Report Name  and....
GrpTotal
Detail
GrpTotalFooter
  subLevel5
  subLevel4
  subLevel3
  subLevel2
  subLevel1
  subLevelSubTotal
GrpPageNumberingFooter
PageFooter
ReportFooter
RptSubReport.vb is the subreport which is designed to be used in all of these 6 subreports.
It has
GrpTitle
   It contains the deign of titles 
grpHeader
grpAlternate
detail
grpfooterAlternate
  It contains the field that should be shown up
grpFooter
  It contains the total sum 
GrpTitlefooter

For subLevel1 to subLevel5 grpfooterAlternate.visible = true and grpFooter.visible = false and
For subLevelSubTotal grpfooterAlternate.visible = False and  and grpFooter.visible = true 
This sets dynamically.

When i run the report with different criterira I get different results.
Some times grpFooter in sub report show up and sometimes it doesn't. I guess it depends on the amount of data showing up in the previous subreports.
It is good to mention that this report used to work correctly but after coversion from framework one to 2, This problem occurs.
I debugged the cases that total sub report show up and the cases that it does not . Both goes through the same events.

Any Body had an idea? I appretiate your help.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

merryca,

I don't believe there is any dependency on FW on rendering of reports.  That  being said, is it possible that you can send us a project that will help us understand what is going on here.  Trying to debug the issue based on your explanation is little bit difficult.

Please email support@grapecity.us.com and we will get you some help immediately.

thanks

raji

Rajnish Sinha,
GrapeCity, inc.

Comment: Thank you so much for your fast respond Rajnish.
After debugging 2 senerio's (The one that works fine and the one 
that does not) as they both fire the same events I hesitated to the groupkeepTogether property. I changed this property for grpTitle from ALL to NONE. Now I can see the Total subreport which is in the grpFooter and the problem is resolved. But I can not understand totally why "ALL" causes this problem!
I hope this change does not cause another issue along the way...
Do you have any idea?